# Changing the Camera at Some Spots Unreal 4 Blueprint

Tags: camera, unreal-4

I'm making a 2D game, and during the level the camera will move together with the player. But in the end, during the final boss, I want the camera to stop and don't move during the fight. 
How I can make it with blueprints on Unreal 4?